# Can't get Javascript to interact with Flash

Tags: javascript, actionscript, flash

I can't get my Javascript to affect my SWF object.
The object is rendered correctly in the browser but I cannot call the "fill" method that I exposed to the ExternalInterface.
The ready function "flashReady" is not called. Directly calling it from the console says that the flash object does not have the function "fill". Waiting for a while then calling the function does not help.

The error is TypeError: `Object HTMLObjectElement has no method 'fill'`

Actionscript code:

```
public class Main extends Sprite
{

  public function Main() {
     graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
     graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
     graphics.endFill();
     Security.allowDomain("*");
     ExternalInterface.addCallback("fill", fill);
     ExternalInterface.call("flashReady");
  }

  public function fill():void {
      graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00);
      graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
      graphics.endFill();
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>
        Flash UI Demo
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function flashReady() {
            document.getElementById('AddCallbackExample').fill();
        }
        var swfVersionStr = "0";
        var xiSwfUrlStr = "";
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};
        params.quality = "high";
        params.bgcolor = "#ffffff";
        params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.id = "AddCallbackExample";
        attributes.name = "AddCallbackExample";
        attributes.align = "middle";
        swfobject.embedSWF(
            "http://localhost:8001/swf", "flash",
            "100%", "100%",
            swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr,
            flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="flash" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I removed the Flex tag; as this has nothing to do with the Flex Framework.

Comment: Try placing `ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "test");` in your Flash to see where exactly the error is occurring and if it's an error in the ActionScript or the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, my version of the library didn't support allowDomain to take in "*" as an argument. I replaced it with "localhost" and it worked.